# Sensitivity of eye

Tags: visible-light, vision

In which color human eye is most sensitive?

Comment: An additional question: what is the quantum efficiency of the eye?

Answer (score 7):

Around 555nm wavelength - green color.
That's why green lasers are soo cool even at 10 mW :-D

[image]

Comment: you can put that link in a `![alt text](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Eyesensitivity.png)` construct to have it shown here directly

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the additional question: "what is the quantum efficiency of the eye?"
I remember old studies reporting that eight photons reaching the photoreceptors can be detected by a human observer as a flash of light in certain laboratory conditions. The more normal range would certainly be lower than 0.125 say 0.05 - 0.01. Cooling down laboratory animals thus reducing thermal noise in the retina enhances sensitivity but means longer integration times and lower spatial and temporal resolution.

Comment: A little late to the party, but this is a nice article that explains those studies and has the references: http://www.desy.de/user/projects/Physics/Quantum/see_a_photon.html

Comment: Cooling down laboratory animals? How did they survive that to be able to actually see? And, BTW, how did they report the flashes they saw?