# Why isn't the sky violet?

Tags: scattering

Why isn't the sky violet? Is there any physical reason why the sky isn't perceived to be violet or is it all in our cones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the sky not purple?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28895/)

Comment: The spectrum of the sky is given by physics, the subjective color of that spectrum by biology, so it's a combination of both.