# The interaction between waves and particles according to their wavelength

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering

Why do EM waves with a large wavelength like those in the red range (and radio waves) interact with particles less than those in the blue range?

That is the reason why the sky is blue, is that right?

Comment: You mean "wavelength" where you say "amplitude", right?

Comment: This is called [Rayleigh scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering).

Comment: yeah! wavelength, sorry.

Comment: See also [Why is the sky not purple?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28895/why-is-the-sky-not-purple) as the answers include some nice descriptions of the physics involved.